# Filtering NAs by group

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements

I have this df

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,3L),
    keyword = c("car","hospital",NA,"cat",NA,NA))
```

I would like to get this

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1L,1L,2L,3L),
    keyword = c("car","hospital","cat",NA))
```

If there is a keyword I would like to keep it and if there is none keep NA

Trying something like

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!is.na(keyword) | keyword != " ")
```

Comment: What if there are multiple keywords that are not NA for an id. (Assuming id is the grouping variable you are talking about)? Also, you could try `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(keyword) %>% summarise(keyword = first(keyword))` This would keep the first non NA (if any) keyword for each id.

Comment: @dario thank you, I made some recommendations from you and provide more similar data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `filter` the rows conditionally.

If in a group, all the `NA` values are present return 1st row else return the non-NA rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(if(all(is.na(keyword))) row_number() == 1 else !is.na(keyword)) %>%
  ungroup

#    id keyword 
#  <int> <chr>   
#1     1 car     
#2     1 hospital
#3     2 cat     
#4     3 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution: First we remove all rows with NA in `keyword` and then we add new rows for the potentially missing `id`s (where all other columns will now contain NA):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(keyword)) %>% 
  full_join(df %>% select(id) %>% unique())
```

Returns:

> ```
>   id  keyword
> 1  1      car
> 2  1 hospital
> 3  2      cat
> 4  3     <NA>
> ```